# How to get xinput to identify an inputer device by name with excess whitespace?

Tags: debian, x11, xrandr, xinput, touch-screen

I have a secondary monitor that is a touch screen.  I can successfully map the input to the correct screen using `xinput map-to-output 12 DP-4`.

However, the ID number for the input device is not consistent between boots.  The way to fix this is to use the name of the device.  However, I have a weird issue:

```
user@DESKTOP-VALMMNL:/etc/init.d$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Weida Hi-Tech                CoolTouchR System            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]`
```

As you can see, the input device I need to map (id=12) has a lot of whitespace in its name. Copying and pasting it as displayed (i.e. `xinput map-to-output "Weida Hi-Tech                CoolTouchR System" DP-4`) does not work.
hexdump of the names:

[image]

Comment: Maybe there's a tab or end-of-line char in the name? What do you see if you do `xinput list --name-only | hexdump -C` (you may need to install hexdump)?

Comment: @dirkt I did try adding in escaped characters, including tabs, but xinput only seemed to recognize escaped spaces.  Putting in \t does not result in a tab.  I added a screenshot of the output from the command you suggested.

Comment: Did you include all the trailing spaces in your command?  Try `xinput --list 'Weida Hi-Tech                CoolTouchR System           '`, since that output shows 11 spaces at the end of the name.  (note that not all the spaces are shown here in the comment - you'll probably have to type them - or `device=\`xinput list --name-only | grep -m1 Weida\`\)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hexdump shows there's only spaces (`20`) in the name, but there are also spaces *after* the second part. So you need to do something like

```
xinput map-to-output "Weida Hi-Tech                CoolTouchR System           " DP-4
```

(I hope I counted correctly; if not, please verify the number of spaces yourself).

Answer (score 0):

```
xinput --map-to-output $(xinput list --id-only "`xinput list --name-only | grep CoolTouch`") DP-4
```